# Filling gaps in timeseries Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, time-series

I have a problem dealing with time-series data. Due power failures some timestamps are missing in the dataset. I need to fill this gaps by adding rows, and after that, I can interpolate the missing values.

Input data:

```
periodstart                usage
---------------------------------
2015-09-11 02:15           23000   
2015-09-11 03:15           23344   
2015-09-11 03:30           23283  
2015-09-11 03:45           23786   
2015-09-11 04:00           25039
```

Wanted output:

```
periodstart                usage
---------------------------------
2015-09-11 02:15           23000   
2015-09-11 02:30           0   
2015-09-11 02:45           0   
2015-09-11 03:00           0   
2015-09-11 03:15           23344   
2015-09-11 03:30           23283   
2015-09-11 03:45           23786   
2015-09-11 04:00           25039
```

Now I have fixed this with a while loop within a dataset foreach function. The problem is that I have to collect the dataset first to the driver before I can do a while loop. So that is not the right way for Spark.

Can someone give me a better solution?

this is my code:

```
MissingMeasurementsDS.collect().foreach(row => {
  // empty list for new generated measurements
  val output = ListBuffer.empty[Measurement]
  // Missing measurements
  val missingMeasurements = row.getAs[Int]("missingmeasurements")
  val lastTimestamp = row.getAs[Timestamp]("previousperiodstart")
  //Generate missing timestamps
  var i = 1
  while (i <= missingMeasurements) {
    //Increment timestamp with 15 minutes (900000 milliseconds)
    val newTimestamp = lastTimestamp.getTime + (900000 * i)
    output += Measurement(new Timestamp(newTimestamp), 0))
    i += 1
  }
  //Join interpolated measurements with correct measurements
  completeMeasurementsDS.join(output.toDS())
})
completeMeasurementsDS.show()
println("OutputDF count = " + completeMeasurementsDS.count())
```

Comment: RHeutz Can you paste your code snippet for adding missing values here?

Answer (score 25):

If input `DataFrame` has following structure:

```
root
 |-- periodstart: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- usage: long (nullable = true)
```

**Scala**

Determine min / max:

```
val (minp, maxp) = df
  .select(min($"periodstart").cast("bigint"), max($"periodstart".cast("bigint")))
  .as[(Long, Long)]
  .first
```

Set step, for example for 15 minutes:

```
val step: Long = 15 * 60
```

Generate reference range:

```
val reference = spark
  .range((minp / step) * step, ((maxp / step) + 1) * step, step)
  .select($"id".cast("timestamp").alias("periodstart"))
```

Join and fill the gaps:

```
reference.join(df, Seq("periodstart"), "leftouter").na.fill(0, Seq("usage"))
```

**Python**

Similarly in PySpark:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, min as min_, max as max_

step = 15 * 60

minp, maxp = df.select(
    min_("periodstart").cast("long"), max_("periodstart").cast("long")
).first()

reference = spark.range(
    (minp / step) * step, ((maxp / step) + 1) * step, step
).select(col("id").cast("timestamp").alias("periodstart"))

reference.join(df, ["periodstart"], "leftouter")
```

Comment: As an fyi you need to do something like `d2 = reference.join(df, ["periodstart"], "leftouter")` at the end in order to capture the output

Comment: Note that if you have a partitioned Dataset as an input and want to fill in the gaps for each partition, you may also add `df.select(partitionByColumns:_*).distinct().crossJoin(reference).join(...)`. This will ensure that missing `periodstart` values will be assigned to each of the partitions.

Comment: @Timur is your suggestion applicable also to this situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526694/pyspark-how-to-groupby-resample-and-forward-fill-null-values/57530922 ?

Comment: @Timur can you say more about your comment? Also looks like scala syntax. And what is the final join for ... ?

Comment: How can we apply the above function per group in a pyspark df?