# Create timeseries (range) between two given timestamp

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a pyspark dataframe **df**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
primaryKey |   start_timestamp   |   end_timestamp
---------------------------------------------------------
 key1      | 2020-08-13 15:40:00 | 2020-08-13 15:44:47
 key2      | 2020-08-14 12:00:00 | 2020-08-14 12:01:13
```

I want to create a dataframe that will have a timeseries that is between start_timestamp and end_timestamp for all keys at a gap of x seconds.
For example for a gap of x = 120 seconds the output will be as:-

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
primaryKey |  start_timestamp_new  | end_timestamp_new
   key1    |  2020-08-13 15:40:00  | 2020-08-13 15:41:59
   key1    |  2020-08-13 15:42:00  | 2020-08-13 15:43:59
   key1    |  2020-08-13 15:44:00  | 2020-08-13 15:45:59
   key2    |  2020-08-14 12:00:00  | 2020-08-14 12:01:59
```

I am trying to use the approach mentiond [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411184/filling-gaps-in-timeseries-spark), but unable to apply it to a spark dataframe.

Any info on creating this will be a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sequence` function.

```
x = 120

df.withColumn('start_timestamp', to_timestamp('start_timestamp')) \
  .withColumn('end_timestamp', to_timestamp('end_timestamp')) \
  .withColumn('start_timestamp', explode(sequence('start_timestamp', 'end_timestamp', expr(f'interval {x} seconds')))) \
  .withColumn('end_timestamp', col('start_timestamp') + expr(f'interval {x - 1} seconds')) \
  .show()

+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|primaryKey|    start_timestamp|      end_timestamp|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|      key1|2020-08-13 15:40:00|2020-08-13 15:41:59|
|      key1|2020-08-13 15:42:00|2020-08-13 15:43:59|
|      key1|2020-08-13 15:44:00|2020-08-13 15:45:59|
|      key2|2020-08-14 12:00:00|2020-08-14 12:01:59|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: then should i use a lead window function on time column ? in order to get the data in the desired output ?

Comment: No, simply add x-1

Comment: can you also help me in this query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000491/get-20th-to-80th-percentile-of-each-group-pyspark