# Get 20th to 80th Percentile of each group - Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, percentile

I have three columns in a pyspark data frame ( sample data given below )

| orderType | customerId | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | c1 | 100.2 |
| A | c2 | 1003.32 |
| B | c1 | 222 |
| C | c3 | 21.3 |
| A | c4 | 1.2 |

I wanted to get the remove the outliers from each orderType. In order to do that I am removing the top Nth Percentile from the data for each orderType.

For example for N = 10, for each group, I will fetch 10th to 90th Percentile data based on the amount and partitionBy orderType.

Need help to implement that for a large dataset ( around 67 million row count ) .

Also can someone help the possible usage of approxquantile on a partion if that is applicale in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `approx_percentile`, then filter:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'percentile',
    F.expr("approx_percentile(amount, array(0.2, 0.8), 100) over (partition by orderType)")
).filter(
    'amount between percentile[0] and percentile[1]'
)
```

Usage of the function is documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#approx_percentile).